# Combination in python using itertools doesn't give correct combination

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

So i want combination of all number from 1 to 5 in 2 length.
I am using below code to get it done.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
 
# Get all combinations of [1, 2, 3] and length 2
comb = combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
 
# Print the obtained combinations
for i in list(comb):
    print (i)
```

the result i get is:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 4)
```

but it is skipping some numbers like (2,1), (3,1), (3,2)

can anyone tell me how can i get all combination including also (1,2), (2,1)
which usually the code skips.

Thanks

---

You have 8 objects: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
All their permutations with repetitions with a sample size of 2 objects:
AA AB BA AC CA AD DA AE EA AF FA AG GA AH HA BB BC CB BD DB BE EB BF FB BG GB BH HB CC CD DC CE EC CF FC CG GC CH HC DD DE ED DF FD DG GD DH HD EE EF FE EG GE EH HE FF FG GF FH HF GG GH HG HH

Comment: I guess you want "itertools.product".

Comment: yes something like above. with all the combinations

Answer (score 1):

You want `itertools.product`. `combinations` never care for the order of elements, `_with_replacement` just allows duplicates:

```
from itertools import product
 
comb = product([1, 2, 3, 4], repeat=2)
for i in comb:  # no list conversion needed
    print(i)

(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 1)
(4, 2)
(4, 3)
(4, 4)
```